# What is the best using for show loading message when request is performing in iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is the best using for show loading message when request is performing in iPhone app? MBProgressHUD or UIAlertView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a subjective question.

MBProgressHUD has more features than UIAlertView so it might be better suited and more easily adapted for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView has its advantages and proves to be useful mostly when application supports all orientations and mainly when you have a split view application.